# Editing a question and asking a completely different question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, asking-questions, title

I am not sure if the title is correct but here is the situation.

[PHP form variables, error for mysql_fetch_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286560/php-form-variables-errors/6286576#6286576)

A question was asked, I answered it, then the OP changed the question without accepting my answer (which was valid for the original question) . What is the proper etiquette to handle such a situation ?

Comment: I've left a comment on the question so at least casual browsers will (hopefully) notice.

Comment: This user hasn't accepted any answer yet. And also no votes cast so that part of the site isn't clear yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the OP is fairly new to Stack Overflow, he/she probably simply doesn't know better. Add a comment to the question explaining why it's not a good idea to change the question in retrospective and that a new question should be opened in these cases, followed by a nice smiley :)

Comment: doesn't this suffice? 'I have updated the answer above. However you should create new questions for new errors :)' .. emphasis on the smiley!

Comment: @Sab: Of course, it's perfect! But your question was what the proper etiquette is, hence my answer.